# Listen All ERC20 transfer event on Specific EOA on ethers.js

Tags: ethers.js, etherscan

I Know there is no way for listening events on EOA since it is not contract.

([ethers.js `filter` not works on EOA](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/issues/2817#issuecomment-1126658596))

But Still, Is there No way for detecting all ERC20 transfer event on specific EOA with `ethers.js`?

Checking All newest block is ok, but which methods needed for this logic?

```js
  provider.on("block", (blockNumber) => {
    // I need the logic here.
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

As an EOA is not a smart contract it doesn't have events you can subscribe to. What you could do is listen to all new blocks, go through all new transactions and then filter for the EOA address. If true, execute your logic.

In case of other options than `ethers`, you can look into API vendors who provide webhook endpoints. Have a look at the [Moralis Streams API](https://docs.moralis.io/streams-api), for example.

If you  want to f.e. listen to `Transfer` event with `ethers` you'll need the ABI of the ERC20 contract you want to watch.

```js
const contractAddress = "0x....."; 
const contractAbi = [ ... ];
const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(); // config your provider
const contract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, contractAbi, provider);

const EOA_ADDRESS_TO_WATCH = "0x.....";

// listen to transfer event
contract.on("Transfer", (from, to, amount, event) => {
  if (from === EOA_ADDRESS_TO_WATCH) {

    // if EOA do your logic
    console.log(`transfer from ${from} to ${to} of ${amount} tokens`);
  }
});
```

Check in new blocks for EOA:

```js
provider.on("block", async (blockNumber) => {

  // Get the block by its block number
  const block = await provider.getBlock(blockNumber);
  
  // go through all tx
  for (const tx of block.transactions) {

    // example to check tx.to or tx.from for EOA
    if (tx.from === EOA_ADDRESS_TO_WATCH || tx.to === EOA_ADDRESS_TO_WATCH) {
      // do something here
    }

    // in this example we check if tx was sent from EOA
    if (tx.from === EOA_ADDRESS_TO_WATCH) {

      // check if tx.to is a contract
      const code = await provider.getCode(tx.to);

      if (code !== "0x") {
        // your logic here if sent to a contract

      } else {
        // other logic here if send to another address
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: So, There is no wild card for catching *All* ERC20's *transfer* event? I mean not single specific ERC20 token but All kinds of ERC20 token which is transferred specific EOA.

Comment: not there is no wildcard for catching **all** ERC20 events, but you can catch all ERC20 events for a contract (if you provide the ABI), and then execute logic based on new events. I updated my answer, maybe an option for you may be an external API / webhook service like moralis. You need to check if this fits your use case.

Comment: @reaverlover did this answer you question? You can try Moralis Streams API to fit your use case. Otherwise there's no way to listen to all ERC20 events with `ethers`, as you always need the ABI for the specific contract. But you can listen to every new block and conditionally execute custom logic (also without having the ABI, see second code example), depending on your needs.

Comment: How about this ? [infura's Track ERC20 transfer example with web3.js](https://community.infura.io/t/web3-js-how-to-track-erc-20-token-transfers-specific-address-token/5571/)
BTW, Seems Moralis one is needed to pay.